# Functions - The line y=mx cuts the graph of y=f(x) in two distinct places. Find all possible values of m.

Tags: functions, absolute-value

[image: Functions]

I understand part *a*: f(x)=-4|x-6|+7, but for part *b* I tried to solve it simultaneously and formed a quadratic equation and then used the discriminant b^2-4ac, and I got m<-28/25, m>28/25, but the answer is -4<m<7/6. Is there an error in my calculations or in the way I solved it?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the simultaneous equations and quadratic equation you formed?

Comment: From your part (a) attempt, $(9,-5)$ is not on your $y=f(x)$: $$-5\ne f(9) = 4\lvert 9-6\rvert + 7 = 19$$.

Comment: Your formulas are hard to read. See the advice here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Not sure why you are solving a quadratic, or where your quadratic comes from.  Anyway, if $m$ is too steep  and positive, the line $y=mx$ passes above the vertex, if $m$ is too steep  and negative negative, it misses the downward sloping side of $f(x).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it geometrically.

$m$ in $y=mx$ is a line with slope $m$ and it passes through the origin.

I would place my ruler fixed at the origin and rotate it around, we can observe two interesting slope.

- If our line is steeper than the line connecting the origin and the vertex, the number of intersection is $0$. Hence find the slope for the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(6,7)$.
- As I further reduce my gradient, it will cut at two places until my line is parallel to the decreasing line. Hence find the slope the line connecting $(6,7)$ and $(9,-5)$.

Our range of interest of $m$ is between the two values.